# Getting text from br tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I almost have a grip on BeautifulSoup4 in Python, but I can't seem to pull out the `<br/>` data for the br tags in HTML data.

**Data Structure:**

```
<HTML and CSS Stuff here>
<div class="menu">
<span class="author">Bob</span> 
<span class="smaller">(06 Jul at 09:21)</span>
<br/>This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit<br/>
</div>
```

**What I'm looking for is:**

```
Author: Bob
Time: (06 Jul at 09:21)
Data: This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit
```

The HTML comes in through `requests`, that all works fine. But I'm just not getting the soup to mix correctly.

**Current Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html_doc = """
<HTML and CSS Stuff here>
<div class="menu">
<span class="author">Bob</span> 
<span class="smaller">(06 Jul at 09:21)</span>
<br/>This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit<br/>
</div>
"""

html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

x = soup.select('div[class="menu"]')
for i in x:
    s = soup.select('span[class="author"]')
    rr = soup.select('span[class="smaller"]')
    for b in s:
        print b
        print rr
```

Comment: Do you have any code for us to help with? Note that there is no text *in* the `<br/>` tag; that tag is always empty. The text comes *after* the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<br/>` tag is an empty tag, always. There is no text in that tag.

What you have instead is text *between* two `<br/>` tags, which may have been confusing. You can drop either tag and it'll still be valid HTML.

You can get text following a tag using the [`.next_sibling` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.select('div.menu br')[0].next_sibling
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html_doc = """
... <HTML and CSS Stuff here>
... <div class="menu">
... <span class="author">Bob</span> 
... <span class="smaller">(06 Jul at 09:21)</span>
... <br/>This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit<br/>
... </div>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> soup.select('div.menu br')[0].next_sibling
u'This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit'
```

Putting that together with extracting all the data:

```
for menu in soup.select('div.menu'):
    author = menu.find('span', class_='author').get_text()
    time = menu.find('span', class_='smaller').get_text()
    data = menu.find('br').next_sibling
```

which produces:

```
>>> for menu in soup.select('div.menu'):
...     author = menu.find('span', class_='author').get_text()
...     time = menu.find('span', class_='smaller').get_text()
...     data = menu.find('br').next_sibling
...     print 'Author: {}\nTime: {}\nData: {}'.format(author, time, data)
... 
Author: Bob
Time: (06 Jul at 09:21)
Data: This message is very important to extract along with the matching author and time of submit
```